# Report dishonest websites to Google Search

Tags: google-search

Often I land on sites via Google Search that provide different content to the user than what is shown to the crawler. For me, this is time-consuming to visit and check pages that are maliciously optimised for Google, full of tracking cookies, ads and with no real useful content.

Is it OK to report these sites? If so, where and how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, it's OK to report those sites.

UPDATE 2018-0813

From [Report spam, paid links, or malware - Google Search Console Help](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93713?hl=en)

> If you find information in Google's search results that you believe result from spam, paid links or malware, here's how you can help.

Please follow the above link to reach the official links.

---

[original link and quote]
From [Report Spam - Google Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1370?hl=en)

> If you've found a site that looks like spam, let us know by
>   [submitting a spam
>   report](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en&pli=1).

---

It's worth to say that there is a Chrome Extension to report web pages as spam to Google. It's [Google Webspam Report (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-webspam-report-by/efinmbicabejjhjafeidhfbojhnfiepj)<sup>1</sup>.

**Notes**
<sup>1</sup>: Thanks to [Al E](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/al-e).